# How add new button to grid product

Tags: magento2, product, grid

I want add new button near Add Product button in grid product in backend.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add new button there using UI Component file. Try to create below `product_listing.xml` file in your custom module.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="new_button" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">new_button</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Button</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</listing>
```

Run below commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this will help you! ;-)

Comment: It work fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidDuong, Welcome Buddy! :-)